# Highlight a range of Y axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How can I highlight a range of Y axis (such as between 80% to 90%) as a green range in `line` highcharts?

I searched for this but found nothing, neither in the web nor in the highcharts documents.

Comment: can you also include you current approach as well in your question. Perhaps your code snippet or a maybe a jsfiddle works just fine?

Comment: Do you mean like this?https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4503423/b6c46c8408009238d09717f76e3031dc

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you had in mind, some image could be useful, but I am guessing that you can highlight some range by using the **plotBand** feature or **zones**.

- PlotBands:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mnd16ok0/

Code:

```
  yAxis: {
    plotBands: [{
        from: 100000,
      to: 125000,
      color: 'green'
    }]
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands

- Zones:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/color-zones/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones